# Creating DB2 XA Datasource using JBoss-CLI

Tags: jboss-cli

I am trying to create DB2 XA Datasource using JBoss-cli using the following command.

```
/profile=full-ha/subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=DB2DSXA3:add(jndi-name="java:/DB2DSXA3",connection-url="jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/TESTDB",driver-name=db2jccxa,is-same-rm-override="false",user-name=sambati,password=Summi135#,recover-plugin-class-name="org.jboss.jca.core.recovery.ConfigurableRecoveryPlugin",valid-connection-checker-class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.db2.DB2ValidConnectionChecker",stale-connection-checker-class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.db2.DB2StaleConnectionChecker",exception-sorter-class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.db2.DB2ExceptionSorter")
```

Looks like some mandatory fields are missing.  i am getting the following error message:

```
connection-url' is not found among the supported properties: [allocation-retry, allocation-retry-wait-millis, allow-multiple-users, authentication-context, background-validation, background-validation-millis, blocking-timeout-wait-millis, capacity-decrementer-class, capacity-decrementer-properties, capacity-incrementer-class, capacity-incrementer-properties, check-valid-connection-sql, connectable, connection-listener-class, connection-listener-property, credential-reference, driver-name, elytron-enabled, enabled, enlistment-trace, exception-sorter-class-name, exception-sorter-properties, flush-strategy, idle-timeout-minutes, initial-pool-size, interleaving, jndi-name, max-pool-size, mcp, min-pool-size, new-connection-sql, no-recovery, no-tx-separate-pool, pad-xid, password, pool-fair, pool-prefill, pool-use-strict-min, prepared-statements-cache-size, query-timeout, reauth-plugin-class-name, reauth-plugin-properties, recovery-authentication-context, recovery-credential-reference, recovery-elytron-enabled, recovery-password, recovery-plugin-class-name, recovery-plugin-properties, recovery-security-domain, recovery-username, same-rm-override, security-domain, set-tx-query-timeout, share-prepared-statements, spy, stale-connection-checker-class-name, stale-connection-checker-properties, statistics-enabled, track-statements, tracking, transaction-isolation, url-delimiter, url-property, url-selector-strategy-class-name, use-ccm, use-fast-fail, use-java-context, use-try-lock, user-name, valid-connection-checker-class-name, valid-connection-checker-properties, validate-on-match, wrap-xa-resource, xa-datasource-class, xa-resource-timeout]
```

can some one help me please.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the `connection-url` is not a property on an `xa-data-source` resource. The connection URL will need to be added as a property in a batch command.

Here's an example MySQL CLI command:

```
module add --name=com.mysql --resources=~/Downloads/mysql-connector-java-5.1.37/mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api

batch
/subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=com.mysql:add(driver-name=com.mysql, driver-module-name=com.mysql, driver-xa-datasource-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource)
/subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=mysql:add(driver-name=com.mysql, jndi-name="java:/jdbc/MySQLXA", enabled=true)
/subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=mysql/xa-datasource-properties=URL:add(value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/temp?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8")
run-batch
```